Why Does SonarQube Pass the Quality Gate for Project A but Fail for Project B Despite Higher Overall Issues?
I'm experiencing a strange behavior in SonarQube with two long-standing projects, Project A and Project B. Both projects have existed for a while across different products, but I'm noticing a discrepancy in how their quality gates are evaluated:
Project A:

Quality Gate: Passed
New Code Statistics:

0 New Bugs
0 New Vulnerabilities
0 New Security Hotspots
0 Added Debt
0 New Code Smells
88.5% Coverage
0.0% Duplications


Overall Code Statistics:

121 Bugs
89 Vulnerabilities
103 Security Hotspots
120d Debt
12k Code Smells
71.4% Code Coverage
3.1% Duplications on 305k Lines



Project B:

Quality Gate: Failed
New Code Statistics:

4 New Bugs
0 New Vulnerabilities
1 New Security Hotspot
20d Added Debt
723 New Code Smells
16.0% Coverage
2.56% Duplications


Overall Code Statistics:

4 Bugs
0 Vulnerabilities
1 Security Hotspot
64d Debt
2.6k Code Smells
16.0% Code Coverage
2.9% Duplications on 98k Lines



My question is:
Why is the quality gate failing for Project B, but not for Project A? Despite Project A having more overall issues, it passes the quality gate, while Project B fails it. What could be the reasons for this discrepancy? Any insights would be appreciated!

Sonar quality gate has 2 modes:

new code
overall code

Seems to me that your quality gate fails on new code metric. More than that, seeing the overall code results, it seems your quality gate either ignores overall code completely, or has low requirements for it, focusing mostly on new code.

The quality gates for Project A have passed for both new code and overall code. However, the quality gate for Project B has failed for both new code and overall code.
I’m wondering why Project A's quality gate has passed, even though it has more issues identified in SonarQube than Project B. Any possible reasons.

Check the quality gate requirements. What you're saying is not possible - either project B failed only on 'new code', or quality gate requirements changed after scan A and before scan B.
